# Configure Group Policy Object with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, gpo

I'd like to configure GPO for multiple computers with powershell, but I'm not able to find proper command and path to GP object.
I need to disallow users to run specific aplications by

> User Configuration > Administrative Templates > System > Don't run specified Windows application

..and specify applications (e.g. wmplayer.exe, vlc.exe, etc.)

What command should I use? Set-GPPrefRegistryValue or Set-GPRegistryValue?

Thanks in advance for any hints!

UPDATE:

I made this script

```
$hostname = "hostname"

$BaseKey = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey( 'CurrentUser' , $hostname )

$SubKey_1 = $BaseKey.OpenSubKey(“Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer\”,$true)

$SubKey_1 = $BaseKey.CreateSubKey(“Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer\DisallowRun”,$true)

$SubKey_1 = $BaseKey.OpenSubKey(“Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer\”,$true)

$ValueName_1 = “DisallowRun”
$ValueData_1 = 1

#DisallowRun DWORD
$SubKey_1.SetValue($ValueName_1, $ValueData_1, [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueKind]::DWORD)

$SubKey_2 = $BaseKey.OpenSubKey(“Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer\DisallowRun”,$true)

#forbidden apps
$1n = "wmplayer"
$1v = "wmplayer.exe"
$2n = "test1"
$2v = "test.exe"
$3n = "calc"
$3v = "calc.exe"

$SubKey_2.SetValue($1n, $1v, [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueKind]::String)
$SubKey_2.SetValue($2n, $2v, [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueKind]::String)
$SubKey_2.SetValue($3n, $3v, [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueKind]::String)
```

But it doesn't work for currently logged user (I can see these values only in regedit opened under my credentials on target computer).
I also tried to made the same under LocalComputer registry - it doesn't work either.

Any ideas?

Comment: 1) Set the values you want in the GPO. You only need to to this once. 2) Link the GPO to an appropriate OU. 3) Put the users in that OU. None of this requires PowerShell.

Comment: I realy need to do this computer by computer - unfortunately all desktops are in the same OU and I can't change it.

Comment: All you need to do is update the GPO that is linked to that OU. You do not need to make the change on each computer. That is one of the main purposes of Group Policy: You make the change in one place, and it applies to all the computers automatically.

Comment: But I need to apply it only for few computers - not all of them in OU.

Comment: You can filter GPOs to apply only to certain computers. This is not a programming or scripting issue.

Comment: OK - seems as the best way. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can find the registry keys for all administrative templates on [getadmx.com](http://getadmx.com/).

[Don't run specified Windows applications on getadmx.com](http://getadmx.com/?Category=Windows_10_2016&Policy=Microsoft.Policies.WindowsTools::DisallowApps)

Comment: eg: REG ADD HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate /v ExcludeWUDriversInQualityUpdate /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f
for https://getadmx.com/?Category=Windows_10_2016&Policy=Microsoft.Policies.WindowsUpdate::ExcludeWUDriversInQualityUpdate